# как работает Vector java

Tags: java, коллекции

Всем привет) интересно узнать, почему класс `Vector` в java потокобезопасен. Документация делает акцент на том что он динамичный, но все же это не совсем то, что нужно. Заглянув в исходники, заметила, что некоторые методы помечены `synchronized`, значит ли это что только один поток имеет доступ к содержимому коллекции?

Comment: Один поток в один момент времени

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, Vector потокобезопасен именно потому, что у него все методы synchronized. Для многопоточки лучше юзать СopyOnWriteArrayList.

Comment: А если я запихну свой vector в stream? Например,
 ```List<MyClass> list = new Vector<();
list.stream
.filter(...)
.forEach(...);
```

Comment: Тогда уж list.stream.parallel :)  По факту - это ничего не поменяет, т.к. стримы - это по сути синтаксический сахар, и под капотом они все равно методы самой коллекции юзают. Т.е. точно также будут использоваться методы Vector, которые synchronized по всей коллекции. И при обращении к любому элементу вся коллекция лочиться будет. В целом - Vector использовать без крайней необходимости не рекомендуется, т.к. это устаревший класс.

Comment: Знаю) стоит задача реализовать потокобезопасное приложение без использования concurrent. Если не ошибаюсь, не стоит юзать из-за производительности, раз уж одним потоком вся коллекция блочится

Answer (score 0):

- Да, только 1 поток имеет доступ единовременно. Методы имеют блоки синхронизированные по this, т.е. блокируется целиком вся коллекция.
- Vector - это старый аналог ArrayList'а. Оба экстендят AbstractList. Vector отличается упомянутой синхронизированностью и размером увеличения внутреннего массива (в ArrayList он увеличивается в 1,5 раза, в Vector в 2 раза). Также стоит упомянуть, что Stack экстендит именно Vector.
- В целом у нас нет причин когда-либо использовать Vector.